# How to invoke enum's method in freemarker?

Tags: enums, freemarker

I have a enum like this:

```
public enum Type{
    A("Title A"),
    B("Title B"),
    C("Title C"),
    D("Title D");

    private String title;

    private Relation(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

I put Title.D to freemarker as type, how could I access the getTitle method?
I tried type.title & type.getTitle(), neither works.
Anybody can help? thx!

Comment: Your example works for me... What's the error message?

Comment: Problem solved, freemarker in project is a very old version, I upgrade it to the latest version, and it works. Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Yuxuan's comment implies that the question has been solved by upgrading to a newer version of Freemarker in the project. My assumption is that the relevant version is [Freemarker 2.3.9](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_9.html). Here, JDK1.5 enum support was added.